# how to use $.when in jquery with any method as a differed?

Tags: jquery, object, jquery-selectors, jquery-deferred

I am wondering if I can use `$.when` with a jquery selector or action as a deferred, like:

```
$.when(newTemplate.appendTo("#container")).done(function(){
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
    console.log(rand);
});
```

`appendTo` might not be async but reads like it would be

Is this going to wait for the `appendTo` to finish?

If not, how can I return a deferred obj from, in this case `appendTo`, so I will know when it is `ready`?

Comment: `appendTo` is synchronous.. I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it's not every day you see a question trying to use sync code in async fashion, it's usually the other way around :P

Comment: @Esailija rofl True that. `:P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous code is always completed before the next line, so you can just

```
newTemplate.appendTo("#container");
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
console.log(rand);
```

What you pass to `$.when` should be an object implementing the [Promise interface](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and encapsulate some asynchronous activity. If the activity is synchronous you can still do it of course but that's complicating the code a lot for absolutely no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: so `rand` will initialize after the appendTo is complete?